# Slow WiFi on my Toshiba

Tags: wireless

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba satellite-L305D. I'v got WiFi speed of 54  Mb/s wile my android tablet has 150 Mb/s. Why is ubuntu so slow?
ps. the prosesor is AMD, I'm not sure but I think the wireless card is anthros. yes the laptop has Ethernet wired conection

Comment: You should add the information of the wireless card of your laptop to your question (sorry, but I don't remember the command). I could be wrong but probably the problem is that the wireless card of your laptop only support IEEE 802.11b/g standar, which maximun allowed synchronization speed is 54Mbps. However your tablet have a recent wireless card whith support for IEEE 802.11n which allows more synchronization speed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you follow [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and provide the data back into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with migrc's comment. Also, check out if anything else(for eg. Software Center) is using your connection during your conn test.